# sum в бесконечном цикле и выводит inf

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Пытаюсь решить задачу условие которой прописано вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот при попытке вывести `sum` вылезает вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить не знаю, но догадываюсь что проблема в первом цикле    `for (int k = 1; abs(term) > eps; k++)`

Вот вся программа:

```
int main()
{
    double eps = 1e-5;
    cout << eps;
    int n, x = 1;
    cin >> n;
    int factorial = 1;
    double sum = 1;
    double term = sum;
    for (int k = 1; abs(term) > eps; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            factorial *= i;
            for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)
            {
                x++;
                sum += pow(x, j + 2) / factorial;
                cout << sum;

            }

        }

    }
    
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: цикл `for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)` - бесконечный. Условие окончания с неправильным индексом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    factorial *= i;
```

Чему равен `factorial` после *первой* итерации? При `i==0`?

И чему равен `sum` после деления на такой `factorial`?

```
sum += pow(x, j + 2) / factorial;
```

Да и потом, ну не так надо такие ряды считать, не вычисляя каждый раз факториал и степень... Рассмотрите отношение двух соседних членов ряда и идите от него.

```
double ch(double x, double eps = 1e-7)
{
    double s = 1, t = 1;
    x *= x;
    for(int k = 1; abs(t) > eps; k += 2)
        s += t *= x/k/(k+1);
    return s;
}
```

Рабочая программа — [здесь](https://ideone.com/Zbd3uu).

Comment: Согласен, ошибка супер глупая, теперь выводит не только inf, а можете прописать адекватно само условие? Потому что я не могу понять как мне задать факториал с шагом 2 в условии, из-за этого цикл не может быть завершен потому что 
`abs(term) > eps` не выполняется никогда

Comment: Я дал рабочий код. Если вы хотите считать сам факториал всякий раз — то надо это делать как минимум с шагом 2, и с типом `double`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!